# Cakephp is adding quotes to my query. How to fix this?

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

Cakephp is adding quotes to my field where i do some postgress functions. I use `$this->paginate` where the fields array looks like this:

```
'fields' => array(  'DealRegistration.id',
'DealRegistration.company_name',
'RequestSpecialPrice.total_price',
'RequestSpecialPrice.request_price',
'RequestSpecialPrice.created',
'RequestSpecialPrice.partner_status',
'RequestSpecialPrice.status',
'RequestSpecialPrice.discount',
"**concat('SP',lpad(CAST(RequestSpecialPrice.deal_registration_id as TEXT),8,'0'))**",
)
```

The query generated by cake looks like this:

```
SELECT concat('SP',lpad(CAST("RequestSpecialPrice"."deal_registration_id" AS **"TEXT"**),8,'0')) FROM table
```

If i remove the quotes from "TEXT" then the query works:

```
SELECT concat('SP',lpad(CAST("RequestSpecialPrice"."deal_registration_id" as **TEXT**),8,'0'))) FROM table
```

How can i force cakephp not to add those quotes?

L.E.
The solution was to use cake's virtual fields.

I've declared:

"concat('SP',lpad(CAST("RequestSpecialPrice"."deal_registration_id" AS **"TEXT"**),8,'0')) as aaa"

as a virtual field in the model and just selected aaa as a field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579258/cakephp-putting-quotes-around-function-name-in-where-clause?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

When using native SQL functions like this, it's usually best to create a virtual field.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html

**app/Model/RequestSpecialPrice.php**

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'my_virtual_field' => "CONCAT('SP', LPAD(CAST(RequestSpecialPrice.deal_registration_id as TEXT), 8, '0'))"
);
```

**Usage**

```
$this->RequestSpecialPrice->find('first', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'DealRegistration.id',
        'DealRegistration.company_name',
        'RequestSpecialPrice.total_price',
        'RequestSpecialPrice.request_price',
        'RequestSpecialPrice.created',
        'RequestSpecialPrice.partner_status',
        'RequestSpecialPrice.status',
        'RequestSpecialPrice.discount',
        'RequestSpecialPrice.my_virtual_field' // Use virtual field
    )
);
```